# Dentist says Dry-Mouth leads to bad breath (halitosis), gingivitis, tooth-decay, periodontal disease, etc. Why isn't Dry-Mouth diagnosed more often?

Tags: dry-mouth, tooth-decay, gingivitis, halitosis-bad-breath

I had my semi-annual check-up with my dentist today and he noted that I had a severely dry-mouth. I've known I had this, but with all my other medical issues, I didn't consider it to be one of my major concerns, and simply dealt with it.

However, my Dentist made it very clear that dry-mouth can be a very serious problem for oral-hygiene. Not only does it lead to bad breath (halitosis), but it can lead to gingivitis, cavities, tooth-decay, and eventually periodontal disease....

1. **Considering how serious dry-mouth is (at least according to my
   dentist), why don't you ever hear people suffering from "dry-mouth"?**
2. **Why don't doctors diagnosis you with dry-mouth? Or if doctors know
   that some of the medications you're on aare known to cause
   dry-mouth, why don't they offer a treatment plan for the symptoms?**
3. **Why isn't dry-mouth taken more seriously?**

Comment: Although I am unfamiliar with this topic, I closely know a dentist who can possibly help you with your question.

Comment: By the way, dentists do see cases of people suffering from dry mouth. And the seriousness of dry-mouth depends.